# UIButton multi-line text with tail truncation

Tags: uibutton, ipad, multiline

I have found similar questions that ask how to have multi-line text on a UIButton, and the solution is to set

```
[myUIButton.titleLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
[myUIButton setTitle:myTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

However, this results in the button title taking up many lines.  I have tried restricting the number of lines using

```
[myUIButton.titleLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
```

but this does not have any affect on the resulting number of lines.

Is there a way to limit the lines word wrapped to 2 lines on the UIButton title, and then have the tail truncated with "..."?

Answer (score 15):

By setting `lineBreakMode` before `numberOfLines` your desired result can be achieved…
This is because `lineBreakMode` seems to cancel out `numberOfLines` set hence we are doing it in this order.

Objective-C:

```
[button.titleLabel setLineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
[button.titleLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
[button setTitle:myTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Swift 3:
from Xcode 6 and above `UILineBreakMode` is replaced by `NSLineBreakMode`

```
button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail
button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
button.setTitle(myTitle, for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Answer (score 3):

I know its been a while since the question was first asked, but I came across the same problem and endend up with a simple but functional solution after considering the answer posted 
[here.](http://the.ichibod.com/kiji/multi-line-uibutton-label-with-tail-truncation-in-ios/)

The solution that worked for me was the following:

```
// Set the line break mode to word wrap so it won't truncate automatically
[button.titleLabel setLineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

// Call a method that truncates the string I want to use
[button setTitle:[self truncateString:myButtonText] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And the truncateString method:

```
- (NSString *)truncateString:(NSString *)stringToTruncate
{
    if ([stringToTruncate length] > 50)
        stringToTruncate = [[stringToTruncate substringToIndex:50] stringByAppendingString:@"..."];

    return  stringToTruncate;
}
```

So basically I calculated the number of characters that would work for my button, and then forced any string longer than that to have the '...' at the end. I know its not the ideal solution but I guess it can work for some of us, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
[button.titleLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
[button.titleLabel setLineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
[button setTitle:myTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

it does it for me! :D
cheers!!

Comment: The setLineBreakMode call seems to cancel out the setNumberOfLines call.  It will truncate the text but doesn't set the number of lines to 2.